# Can I determine which paths RubyGems added to the load path to make my command line app work?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems, load-path

In a gemspec, I can specify the `require_paths`, which represent paths I want to be able to require from at runtime.  These get put into the `$LOAD_PATH` by RubyGems.

My question is: is there a way I can determine what these paths are at runtime?  Can I examine elements of `$LOAD_PATH` and know which ones were added just for my gem?

**Update**: Ultimately, I would like to dynamically load ruby files from inside the gem, e.g.

```
load_from 'foo/bar'
```

And have that find `$MY_GEMS_LIB_DIR/foo/bar/*.rb`.  I can certainly go through the entire `$LOAD_PATH` looking for `foo/bar`, but I'd rather restrict it just to the gem.

Comment: could you explain what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: updated the question with more info

Comment: Why don't you use something like `File.expand_path('../bar', __FILE__)` to get an absolute path? (if I understand you correctly, you want to load your own files)

Comment: It's for code that's in a library that will be used by a command-line app distributable as a RubyGem.  So `__FILE__` is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @davetron5000 any luck? I was about to suggest something similar to what undur_gongor suggested, below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your needing (my english is bad :-/ ); anyway, if the problem is to determine the directories that will be loaded when you require a gem you can use [`Gem::Specification.lib_dirs_glob`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L1757):

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('irbtools').lib_dirs_glob
#=> "/home/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/irbtools-1.2.2/lib"

Gem::Specification.find_by_name('xyz').lib_dirs_glob
# raises a Gem::LoadError
```

So a possible implementation of `load_from` could be:

```
def load_from(gem_name, path)
  path_to_load = File.join(Gem::Specification.find_by_name(gem_name).lib_dirs_glob, path)
  Dir.glob(path_to_load).each(&method(:load))
end
```

Trying to load `Thor::CoreExt` :

```
Thor::CoreExt #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Thor
load_from 'thor', 'thor/core_ext/*.rb'
Thor::CoreExt #=> Thor::CoreExt
```

This works on my machine with ruby 1.9.3 and gem 1.8.21 .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do (Ruby 1.9.3):

```
before = $LOAD_PATH.dup
require 'the_gem'
added_paths = $LOAD_PATH - before
```

Of course, this will include the paths added by the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$:` global in irb. There is also the `gem which` command which gives you a library path, but I'm not sure if that includes exactly what you want.

Comment: That is how one access the load path.  I know how to do that.  I want to see what part of the load path was modified by RubyGems specific to my app

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Gem.find_files](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems.rb#L454) may help you.

Comment: That's not quite it; it seems to search within the installed gems.  Perhaps what I want is not possible.  I was hoping I could intercept the load paths added by the gem in which my code is currently running.

Comment: @davetron5000 BTW gem's load path can be added to `$LOAD_PATH` by Bundler. In that case Rubygems activation mechanism won't be used at all.

Comment: Would that happen for a command-line app installed via RubyGems?

Comment: @davetron5000 Ah, I was inattentive to your previous comment about command-line app. Of course no, unless you `require 'bundler/setup'` yourself.